# Having trouble adding together elements from array

Tags: java, arrays, function

I have to write a program that uses two classes to create a grocery list. The first class creates an array to hold the values gotten from the second class. The array holds grocery items which have a name, quantity, and price value. I have a function that is supposed to get a total cost of everything in the array, but for some reason the function is only adding the last item that is added to the array to itself. Here's my code:

```
public class GroceryList {

private GroceryItemOrder[] groceryList = new GroceryItemOrder[0];
private int numofEntries;

public GroceryList()
{
    this.groceryList = new GroceryItemOrder[10];
    this.numofEntries = 0;
}

public void add(GroceryItemOrder item)
{
    if(numofEntries == 10)
    {
        System.out.println("The list is full.");
    }
    else
    {
        groceryList[numofEntries] = item;
        numofEntries++;
    }

}

public double getTotalCost()
{
    double totalCost = 0;
    double newCost = 0;

    for(int size = 0; size < numofEntries; size ++)
    {
        newCost = groceryList[size].getCost();
        totalCost = newCost + totalCost;
    }

    return totalCost;


}



public class GroceryItemOrder {

private static double pricePerUnit;
private static int quantity;
private String name;

public GroceryItemOrder(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
}


public static double getCost()
{
    return (quantity * pricePerUnit);
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity)
{
    this.quantity = quantity;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GroceryList newList = new GroceryList();

    newList.add(new GroceryItemOrder("cookies", 1, 1.50));
    newList.add(new GroceryItemOrder("cheese", 2, 1.0));
    newList.add(new GroceryItemOrder("bread", 1, 5.0));

    System.out.println(newList.getTotalCost());

}
}
```

In the function I was trying to use a for loop that would run through the array one element at a time and take whatever values were stored into the element and store it into a new object. I feel like I'm heading in the right direction but can't figure out where the issue is with the function. Can anyone see where my issue is, or at least give me some advice on how I can begin to attempt to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 of your 3 variables in `GroceryItemOrder` are `static`, which means only one variable for the entire class, not one for each instance.  Each new instance overwrites the values set by the previously created instance.

Make all of those instance variables not `static`:

```
private double pricePerUnit;
private int quantity;
private String name;
```

Comment: Thank you! Changing those from static and the function getCost() from static fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The static modifier to `quantity` and `pricePerUnit` makes no sense if you want to have some variety in your grocery. What happens is that each time you call the constructor or GroceryItemOrder, you change those two static fields, so if affects the total price of all the previous orders created. The rest is fine even if it could be more concise sometimes.